# Polylines get connected from start and end | Google Maps | Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, google-polyline

Problem is that when I draw polylines, they get connected from start and end point which is not supoosed to. I simply decode my polypoints (which are encoded strings from direction api) and then add them to polyoptions to draw polylines on map.

Here is my code below:

```
val options = PolylineOptions()
    options.color(Color.RED)
    options.width(10f)
    val list = booking.polyPointsList.flatMap { it.decodePoly() }
    options.addAll(list)
```

whats inside decodepoly()

```
fun String.decodePoly(): MutableList<LatLng> {
if (this.isEmpty()) return mutableListOf()
val poly = ArrayList<LatLng>()
var index = 0
val len = this.length
var lat = 0
var lng = 0

while (index < len) {
    var b: Int
    var shift = 0
    var result = 0
    do {
        b = this[index++].toInt() - 63
        result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
        shift += 5
    } while (b >= 0x20)
    val dlat = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
    lat += dlat

    shift = 0
    result = 0
    do {
        b = this[index++].toInt() - 63
        result = result or (b and 0x1f shl shift)
        shift += 5
    } while (b >= 0x20)
    val dlng = if (result and 1 != 0) (result shr 1).inv() else result shr 1
    lng += dlng

    val p = LatLng(
        lat.toDouble() / 1E5,
        lng.toDouble() / 1E5
    )
    poly.add(p)
}

return poly
```

}

[image: See Polylines here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably in your decoded polyline point with start location coordinates exists twice as first and last point. So, try to remove last point in your list:

```
val options = PolylineOptions()
    options.color(Color.RED)
    options.width(10f)
    val list = booking.polyPointsList.flatMap { it.decodePoly() }
    list.removeLast() 
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - add this line
    options.addAll(list)
```

Or, may be you add all of polyline points twice (or more). In that case "first point" also exists in polyline points at least twice:

```
     +--------------------- Cycle --------------------+
     |                                                |
first_point -> second_point -> ... last_point -> first_point -> ... -> last_point
\____________________  _____________________/    \__________   _________________/
                      V                                      V
        first time added points list               second time added points list
```

Comment: Thanks for your precious time to answer this, I thought the same and tried to remove the last element from list but result was the same. Nothing happened.
Also, removing a LatLng from list can effect of connected lines betweek two different locations?

Comment: Please double check the coordinates of polyline: maybe its points added twice and you need to delete all points of copy not only the last one.  Polyline is connected because its first point occurs twice.

Comment: Thanks brother for you time and effort I checked and accidentally initial location was being added twice in a loop for some logic.